# How I can connect my windows form application with any website on internet?

Tags: c#

I want to link data from website on internet to my windows form application (when data is update in website , it is update in my windows form application) , How I can do this ?
I used C# and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: This question could use some more info, please explain what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the internet works. Things you can do (as long as you've checked the Terms of Service for the site you're interested in):

- display a web-page in a hosted browser control
- query data via API published by the site's owners (which might be on a sub-domain or a different domain entirely)
- subscribe to some push notification API for change notification, for example web-sockets or long-polling offered by the site you're talking to

  - or refresh on an interval